# Form auto submit only once and reload same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom-events, backend

I have created a form in php which has to fetch data from `table1` and dump it into `table2` every time user clicks on a link (link provided in a different page). I have written code in a php page (assume eg -> test.php) including html as well. I tried submitting the form `onload` of the page using Javascript (`document.formname.submit`)  but it keeps on going in an infinite loop and keeps inserting data in `table2` again and again.

How do I prevent this and auto form submit only once and still stay on the same PHP (i.e. test.php) page, which also contains the code for displaying detail view of  the inserted data in `table2`?

Comment: provide your code here

Comment: Write boolean to a local storage when form submitted, and chech this value, before form submitted

Comment: Please provide some of your code. else it will be difficult to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

That's because simply calling `submit()` on a form fill cause a full page reload. If you want to keep the current approach, you should instead use AJAX call to submit the data from that form.

[Read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) for more details. The article explains how to do both GET and POST requests using JS.

That sad, your solution seems somewhat ... emm ... hairy. Why exactly are you copying data from no table top another?

Answer (score 0):

Before JavaScript check this condition by using form name.

```
 if ( ! isset($_POST['main']) )
```

Here main is form name.